# Without using integration and a graphing calculator, plot the graph of $y=f(x)$, given that its derivative is $f'(x)=e^{-x^{2}}$ and $f(0)=0$.

Tags: calculus

With my little understanding of calculus, I calculated $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f'(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} f'(x)=0$. Based on this information, I guessed that the graph must flatten for extremely large(whether positive or negative) values of $x$. Further, $$f''(x)=-2xe^{-x^{2}}$$ From this, I deduced that for $x<0$ the slope is increasing, while for $x>0$, the slope is decreasing. Given that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$, the graph passes through the origin. Based on all this information, I figured the graph looks like this [image: original]

The only part I failed to figure out is this:

> **How to calculate the value of horizontal asymptotes enclosing the graph? Can this be done without explicitly involving integration?**

Comment: Do you want to know how it can be done via integration?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Sure, but that'll be additional information. I'm interested to know if it can be done *without integration*.

Comment: In other words:  evaluate $\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^2)\;dx$ without integration.  I assume "without integration" allows neither multiple integration nor contour integration and residue theory.  The only way to do that I can think of is: look it up.

Comment: @GEdgar I'd appreciate that as an answer.

Comment: When this type of question is asked, an approximate sketch of the graph is sufficient.  You just want to get the shape right.  Getting the exact values of the asymptotes is not the ask.

Comment: @Paul So are you saying that it is"impossible" to find the exact values of asymptotes without imploring some form of integration?

Comment: @Paul Found it more convenient to plot a graph online than to capture a photo and upload it. I think it's not relevant to what is being asked, though.

Comment: Yes, you need integration to find the exact values.  So since that is not allowed, the exact values are not within scope of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to calculate the value of horizontal asymptotes enclosing the graph? Can this be done without explicitly involving integration?

In other words: evaluate $\int_0^\infty \exp(-x^2)\;dx$ without integration. I assume "without integration" allows neither multiple integration nor contour integration and residue theory. The only way to do this that I can think of is: look it up.

---

Relating to the contour integration method:

Desbrow, Darrell.

[On Evaluating $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ax(x-2b)}\, dx$ by Contour Integration Round a Parallelogram](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2588989).

Amer. Math. Monthly $105\, (1998)$, no. $8,\, 726–731$.

Comment: The solution to the question utilised the evenness of the function to claim that the asymptotes were symmetric, i.e., $c$ and $-c$. However, it was mentioned that *it is not clear at this point in the course whether c is finite or infinite*. So without integration, can I not even be sure that $c$ has a finite value?

Comment: @Manan i think so.....because you are trying to comment on the exact value of a function, from its derivative (if you don't integrate)......if you, by any means try to go to the value of the function, you will be solving the DE, or integrating (in other words)

Comment: @SaketGurjar But $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=0$(for negative infinity too). Doesn't that mean there should be a finite value of asymptote $c$ enclosing the curve?

Comment: @Manan Consider the function $f(x)=\log x$....for this, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, so $\lim_{x \to 
 \infty} f'(x)$ is $0$, but $\lim f(x)$ is not finite

Comment: @SaketGurjar That seems to be a good example.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: This is done by integration, so count it as "additional information" as said in the comments.

$$f'(x)=e^{-x^2}$$

$$\int_0^{f(x)} \,d(f(x)) = \int_0^x e^{-x^2}\,dx $$

$$f(x)=\int_0^x e^{-x^2}\,dx$$

The function $y=e^{-x^2}$ should be familiar to you. It is the curve that defines the normal or gaussian distribution function.

[[image: <span class=]$y=e^{-x^2}$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvB41.png)

Let's first look at the integral from $x=-\infty$ to $\infty$, rather than $x=0$ to $x$

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ consider two curves: $z=e^{-x^2}$ and $z=e^{-y^2}$.

Both of these stand vertically upon the x-y plane, with their peaks pointing in the direction of the z-axis.

[image]

The two areas under these curves would be the same: $A=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx$ and $A=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}\,dy$

Multiplying the two will give the volume of a 3-Dimensional bell-shaped curve as shown above (the right hand sketch)

We get :

$$A^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx \times \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}\,dy$$

This gives a nested double integral:

$$A^2= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy$$

Now we can shift to polar co-ordinates ($r,\theta$), where r is polar radius vector of any point (x,y)

Let us view that 3-D bell curve as a solid of revolution created by rotating the curve $z=e^{-r^2}$, stretching from $r=0$ to $r=\infty$ about the z-axis, through an angle equal to $2\pi$ radians. We will have to change the limits of our double integrals accordingly.

We will also have to redefine that double integral from  $$  &  $$  to  $$  &  $$ , to adapt to a polar world. In the Cartesian World, the volume of a 3D solid is computed by adding the volumes of an infinite number of thin, vertical columns of square cross-section  $\,\,$. In the polar world, the same solid has to be imagined as being made of an infinite number of very tiny, concentric arc-shaped sections of radial thickness  $$  and arc-width  $$

[image]

Our new equation will then be:-

$$A^2= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} re^{-r^2} \,d{\theta}\,dr$$

$$A^2=\left( \int_0^{2\pi} \,d{\theta} \right) \left( \int_0^\infty re^{-r^2}\,dr \right)$$

$$A^2=(2\pi) \left( \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} e^{-u}\,du \right) $$

$$A^2=\pi$$

$$A=\sqrt\pi$$

So, $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt\pi$$

Now, to calculate the integral we require, let's resume at equation $A^2=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty re^{-r^2} \,d\theta \,dr$

Let us switch limits of $r$ to : $r=0$ to $r=x$

We get the volume of our 3D solid to be :

$$A^2=\left( \int_0^{2\pi} \,d{\theta} \right) \left( \int_0^x re^{-r^2}\,dr \right)$$

$$=(2\pi)\left( \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{x^2} e^{-u}\,du \right)$$

$$A^2=\pi \times (1-e^{-x^2})$$

$$A=\sqrt{\pi (1-e^{-x^2})}$$

Now notice that the volume used here was the volume of our 3D bell shaped solid, but truncated at a radius of $x$. Something like:

[image]

So, the $A$ is actually $\int_{-x}^x e^{-x^2}\,dx$

But by the circular symmetry, $\int_0^x e^{-x^2}\,dx$ will be half of this $A$

Thus, finally:

$$\int_0^{x} e^{-x^2} \,dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi (1-e^{-x^2})} = f(x) $$

NOTE: this is only for $x>0$. For $x<0$ consider the negative part while taking the square root of $A^2$.

So the asymptotes can be found by applying the $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}$ on $f(x)$

NOTE: for $x<0$, $f(x)=- \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi (1-e^{-x^2})}$

Comment: Really appreciate the effort, although I'm still taking a course in single variable calculus, so most of the answer seems inaccessible to my understanding(*I hardly understand methods of integration in one variable so far*).

Comment: @Manan there are quite a lot of sources for it on the internet.......you can read it in your free time.....I too have not received formal education in double integrals as i'm not in college yet.....but the time spent in it will be worth your while...trust me

Comment: I'm currently going through MIT OCW's 18.01SC to understand single variable calculus deeply. This question popped up in one of their exercises; and yes, I'm looking forward to studying multivariate calculus once I finish this course.